More than one input type file in react-use-file-upload
I am using react-use-file-upload.
Given below is the doc example:
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import useFileUpload from 'react-use-file-upload';

const Upload = () => {
  const {
    files,
    fileNames,
    fileTypes,
    totalSize,
    totalSizeInBytes,
    handleDragDropEvent,
    clearAllFiles,
    createFormData,
    setFiles,
    removeFile,
  } = useFileUpload();

  const inputRef = useRef();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = createFormData();

    try {
      axios.post('https://some-api.com', formData, {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to submit files.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div css={CSS}>
      <h1>Upload Files</h1>

      <p>Please use the form to your right to upload any file(s) of your choosing.</p>

      <div className="form-container">
        {/* Display the files to be uploaded */}
        <div css={ListCSS}>
          <ul>
            {fileNames.map((name) => (
              <li key={name}>
                <span>{name}</span>

                <span onClick={() => removeFile(name)}>
                  <i className="fa fa-times" />
                </span>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>

          {files.length > 0 && (
            <ul>
              <li>File types found: {fileTypes.join(', ')}</li>
              <li>Total Size: {totalSize}</li>
              <li>Total Bytes: {totalSizeInBytes}</li>

              <li className="clear-all">
                <button onClick={() => clearAllFiles()}>Clear All</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          )}
        </div>

        {/* Provide a drop zone and an alternative button inside it to upload files. */}
        <div
          css={DropzoneCSS}
          onDragEnter={handleDragDropEvent}
          onDragOver={handleDragDropEvent}
          onDrop={(e) => {
            handleDragDropEvent(e);
            setFiles(e, 'a');
          }}
        >
          <p>Drag and drop files here</p>

          <button onClick={() => inputRef.current.click()}>Or select files to upload</button>

          {/* Hide the crappy looking default HTML input */}
          <input
            ref={inputRef}
            type="file"
            multiple
            style={{ display: 'none' }}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setFiles(e, 'a');
              inputRef.current.value = null;
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="submit">
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

But the problem is, currently in my component, I have more than one input type file.
So, I am confused, how can I manage all my file inputs by using this library.
If anyone already did, please help!
Note: I want feature like :
<input />
<input />
.
.
.

all inputs are of type file.

It's hard to diagnose the problem without seeing your code. Are both file inputs using react-file-upload? Why do you want to use separate inputs? Perhaps you will need to call the useFileUpload twice. If that is the case I would suggest making a component to do it.

Suppose we do want to use more than one input in the doc example. A component can have more than one input for upload profile_pic, id_proof, graduation_certificate etc etc. Then how you achieve this ?

Or, will it be easier if I just use native HTML input="file" name="unique" instead of using library ?

Make a separate component called fileUploader which has the hook in. Then onSubmit, use a setter that is passed from the component to track the files in each componenet. Then when the full form is submitted. Handle the upload of the files then. Where are you uploading the files too? BTW I use this library https://uploadthing.com/ for my file uploads. It works well in NextJS but I think it would be applicable to any react app too

Thanks for the help, I solved the problem by making a separate component FileUploader.

Thanks, please give me some karma for the help :)

I didn't get, How can I give you karma ?

Create a reusable component for FileUploader:
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import useFileUpload from 'react-use-file-upload';

/**
 * @param {*fieldName} props
 * fieldName is related to the unique name of the input field, like profile_pic, id_proof
 * @returns 
 */
const FileUploader = (props) => {
    const { multiple = false, uploadButtonLabel = "Or select files to upload", onFilesSelected, fieldName } = props;
    const {
        files,
        fileNames,
        fileTypes,
        totalSize,
        totalSizeInBytes,
        handleDragDropEvent,
        clearAllFiles,
        createFormData,
        setFiles,
        removeFile,
    } = useFileUpload();

    const inputRef = useRef();


    useEffect(() => {
        if (onFilesSelected) {
            onFilesSelected(files, fieldName); // Pass the selected files and field name to the parent component
        }
    }, [files, onFilesSelected, fieldName]);

    // const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    //     e.preventDefault();

    //     const formData = createFormData();
    //     try {
    //         console.log('formData', formData);
    //     } catch (error) {
    //     }
    // };

    return (
        <div>
            {/* <h1>Upload Files</h1> */}
            <div className="form-container">
                {/* Display the files to be uploaded */}
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        {fileNames.map((name) => (
                            <li key={name}>
                                <span>{name}</span>
                                <span onClick={() => removeFile(name)}>
                                    <i className="" />
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>

                    {files.length > 0 && (
                        <ul>
                            <li>File types found: {fileTypes.join(', ')}</li>
                            <li>Total Size: {totalSize}</li>
                            {/* <li>Total Bytes: {totalSizeInBytes}</li> */}

                            <li className="clear-all">
                                <button onClick={() => clearAllFiles()}>Clear All</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    )}
                </div>

                {/* Provide a drop zone and an alternative button inside it to upload files. */}
                <div
                    onDragEnter={handleDragDropEvent}
                    onDragOver={handleDragDropEvent}
                    onDrop={(e) => {
                        handleDragDropEvent(e);
                        setFiles(e);
                    }}
                >
                    <p>Drag and drop files here</p>

                    <button type="button" onClick={() => inputRef.current.click()}>{uploadButtonLabel}</button>

                    {/* Hide the default HTML input */}
                    <input
                        ref={inputRef}
                        type="file"
                        multiple={multiple}
                        style={{ display: 'none' }}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            setFiles(e);
                            inputRef.current.value = null;
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* <div className="submit">
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </div> */}
        </div>
    );
};

export default FileUploader;

Then parentComponent will look like :
    const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);

    const handleFilesSelected = (files, fieldName) => {
        setSelectedFiles(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [fieldName]: files
        }));
    };
 <FileUploader
   uploadButtonLabel="Click to Upload"
   onFilesSelected={handleFilesSelected}
   fieldName={"proof_id"}
/>

<FileUploader
   uploadButtonLabel="Click to Upload"
   onFilesSelected={handleFilesSelected}
   fieldName={"address_proof"}
/>

